# what is the difference between "location /logs" and "location /logs/" in nginx.conf

Tags: java, security, nginx, webserver, nginx-config

I need to know the difference between the following two lines in **nginx.conf**. and their use cases too.

**location /logs {**

**location /logs/ {**

Comment: The main difference is that only one will match the URI `/logsfoo` and only one will match the URI `/logs`.

Comment: @RichardSmith,
sorry can you explain me clearly?

Comment: @RichardSmith  Did you mean that the first one will match /logsanything and second one will match /logs alone

Comment: No. My comment was ambiguous, sorry. These are prefix locations so they match URIs that **begin with** the characters in the value. So only the first location block can match `/logs` and `/logsx` because the sixth character in the URI is not a `/`. The rules for matching URIs to location blocks is explained [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) and [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location).

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in the location documentation at http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location

> If a location is defined by a prefix string that ends with the slash character, and requests are processed by one of proxy_pass, fastcgi_pass, uwsgi_pass, scgi_pass, memcached_pass, or grpc_pass, then the special processing is performed. In response to a request with URI equal to this string, but without the trailing slash, a permanent redirect with the code 301 will be returned to the requested URI with the slash appended. If this is not desired, an exact match of the URI and location could be defined like this:

```
location /user/ {
    proxy_pass http://user.example.com;
}

location = /user {
    proxy_pass http://login.example.com;
}
```

I hope that helps.